# Edit PHP query code depending on image map clicked area using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

So I have an image map on my website (with usemap and areas), and when I click on a specific area I want specific MySQL queries to be executed. Basically it's a table that should show different data on the same page when clicking on a specific area of the image map. Figured that I have to use jQuery or AJAX (I'm a beginner with this stuff).

Here's the image map:

```
<img id="harta" src="img/hartap.png" alt="testmap" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area class="area1" alt="area1" title="area1" href="#table" shape="poly" coords="898,3071,902,3553,1108,3561,1129,3419,1254,3419,1278,3273,1472,3261,1476,3100" />
    <area class="area2" alt="area2" title="area2" href="#table" shape="poly" coords="842,2759,846,3035,1896,3076,1917,2816,1345,2774" />
    <area class="area3" alt="area3" title="area3" href="#table" shape="poly" coords="942,2327,934,2752,1342,2764,1380,2333" />
</map>
```

And here's the section with PHP code:

```
<section id="table" class="row">
<?php

    require_once('config.php');

      $reg = "theclickedarea"; // THIS VARIABLE HAS TO BE MODIFIED DEPENDING ON THE CLICKED AREA

      $con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die(mysql_error());
      $db = mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die(mysql_error());
      $sql=mysql_query("SELECT name, score FROM table WHERE game='".$reg."'") or die(mysql_error());
      $count=0;

    echo  '<table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>score</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
       $name=$row['name'];
       $score=$row['score'];

       echo 
           '<tr>
               <td>'.$name.'</td>
               <td>'.$score.'</td>
           </tr>';

       $count++;   
    }
    echo ' </tbody> </table>  ';

?>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use jQuery to do this. First you should bind an event listener for click on the area element. Then get its value and make a GET request with the area title as a parameter to the PHP script using AJAX. The PHP script would query the database and build a response, which you will then feed to the page.

Below is the jQuery to add event listener and get the area value and call the PHP script.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.area').bind("click", function () {
                var area = $(this).attr('title');
                var response = getTable(area);

                $('#table-holder').html(response);

            });

                function getTable(area) {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                var httpURL = "the_php_page.php?area=" + area;
                xhttp.open("GET", httpURL, false);
                xhttp.send();
                return xhttp.responseText;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

The html page becomes something like the below. Note that I have changed the class of the area elements to the same class because I get them by class in the jQuery.

```
<img id="harta" src="img/No_Image_Available.png" alt="testmap" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
        <area class="area" alt="area1" title="area1" href="#table" shape="poly" coords="898,3071,902,3553,1108,3561,1129,3419,1254,3419,1278,3273,1472,3261,1476,3100" />
        <area class="area" alt="area2" title="area2" href="#table" shape="poly" coords="842,2759,846,3035,1896,3076,1917,2816,1345,2774" />
        <area class="area" alt="area3" title="area3" href="#table" shape="poly" coords="942,2327,934,2752,1342,2764,1380,2333" />
</map>

<div id="table-holder"></div>
```

Finally, the PHP which is a separate file becomes something like:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

$reg = $_GET['area']; // THIS VARIABLE HAS TO BE MODIFIED DEPENDING ON THE CLICKED AREA

$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die(mysql_error());
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT name, score FROM table WHERE game='" . $reg . "'") or die(mysql_error());
$count = 0;

$response = '<table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>score</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $name = $row['name'];
    $score = $row['score'];

    $response .= '<tr>
                        <td>' . $name . '</td>
                        <td>' . $score . '</td>
                     </tr>';

    $count++;
}
$response .= ' </tbody> </table>  ';
header('Content-type: text/plain');
exit($response);
?>
```

Moreover, consider using my **mysqsli** for SQL connection as **mysql** is deprecated. 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, buddy! I'm going to check it out in a bit and I'll get back to you as fast as possible.

Comment: It works. Never would've figured. Best of wishes to you, buddy!

Comment: I am glad to help. :)